# Autoload'd calls fail via Inline::Perl5 in Raku

Tags: perl, raku, chart-director

I'm rewriting some perl/charting software in Raku but have run into an issue using the ChartDirector perl5 module (link below) via Inline::Perl5.   The module is basically a perl interface to a DLL; using the module via Inline::Perl5 seems to work for method calls explicitly included in the code - but most of the method calls are executed via the autoload 'catch all' mechanism in perl5.   These do not work in my raku code.

My question is can I expect this sort of application to work using Inline::Perl5?  (perhaps there is no way to 'catch' these autoload'd method calls) and, if so, how to make it so.

Thanks for any pointers, suggestions.

wf

---

ChartDirector software (excellent graphics/charting software - have used it for nearly 2 decades with perl): https://www.advsofteng.com/index.html

---

Quoting verbiage (simplified), version info, and code from [the start of a chartdir forum thread about this](https://www.chartdir.com/forum/download_thread.php?site=chartdir&bn=chartdir_support&thread=1650985909):

> I'm using [`Inline::Perl5`](https://github.com/niner/Inline-Perl5) which works with every other module I've tried.
>
> I'm hitting problems reproducing [the "first project" example on the chartdir site](https://www.advsofteng.com/doc/cdperldoc/firstproject.htm).
>
> using chartdir 6, freebsd 12.2 (intel platform), raku 2022.04, perl 5.32.1.

```
#!/usr/bin/env raku

use lib:from<Perl5>  '/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl';
use Inline::Perl5;

my $p5 = Inline::Perl5.new;
$p5.use('perlchartdir') ;

my $data = [85, 156, 179.5, 211, 123];
my $labels = ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri"];

my $c = $p5.invoke( 'XYChart', 'new', 250, 250);

$c.setPlotArea(30, 20, 200, 200);

$c.addBarLayer($data);
$c.xAxis().setLabels($labels);
$c.xAxis().setLabels($labels);

$c.makeChart("simplebar.png");
```

> All seems fine (i.e., data-dumping `$c` after line 8 shows a large/reasonable looking structure) until line 9 where I receive "No such method `setPlotArea` for invocant of type `XYChart`".  Line 10 does appear to work (no complaints) - remaining 3 lines don't (same type of error as for line 8).

---

And quoting some feedback that was given by Peter Kwan, the primary dev of chartdir:

> I have never used Raku before. For your case, the methods that fail seem to be AUTOLOAD methods. ... I suspect may be Raku does not support Perl AUTOLOAD, so it reports undefined methods as not found instead of forwarding it to the "catch all" method. Or may be some additional things need to be imported for it to use the AUTOLOAD.

As dwarring notes in the comments below this SO question, Inline::Perl5 does support autoload (and has for 7 years), so perhaps that aspect is a red herring?

---

gratefully responding to p6steve's response, I am providing some additional information ..

The full output from various representations of $c (the XYChart object) is included here:  https://pastebin.com/gY2ibDaM  (hope it's ok to use pastebin for this (still finding my way through stackoverflow)) - the output was 600+ lines long and wasn't sure what I could usefully edit out).

to summarize though ..

dd $c returns nil (although prints out the equivalent of $c.perl (below) to stdout (not sure why))

say $c.perl returns:

XYChart.new(inline-perl5 => Inline::Perl5.new(thread-id => 1), wrapped-perl5-object => NativeCall::Types::Pointer.new(34651088744))

say $c.^methods returns:

(WHERE addHLOCLayer ACCEPTS WHY can new isa rakuseen defined getYCoor addHLOCLayer3 raku yZoneColor Numeric addLineLayer addAreaLayer DESTROY BUILDALL gist perl WHICH sink bless getYValue Str addBarLayer new_shadow_of_p5_object AT-KEY)

finally, say Dump $c (using Data::Dump module) yields about 600 lines of output (included in the pastebin output).

Comment: Inline::Perl5 test suite includes autoload tests (https://github.com/niner/Inline-Perl5/blob/master/t/autoload.t). So it is handled in general. Can you please include a code sample here on SO?

Comment: Thank you for the follow-up and helpful rephrasing of (and adding context re:) question.   I'll continue to explore and post any new information I find - there is surely something simple I'm missing/failing to do.  (the raku code included in the rephrase above is complete)

Comment: "using chartdir 6, freebsd 12.2 (intel platform), raku 2022.04, perl 5.32.1" — chartdir 6 only seems to include support for perl versions up to 5.30. Can you try 7.0?

Answer (score 3):

Hi wingfold and welcome to the raku SO tag!

I wonder what you get with `dd $c;` just before the line `$c.setPlotArea(30, 20, 200, 200);` - e.g. is $c truly an XYChart object?

If so then what does `$c.^methods` (the '^' indicates a meta method ... in this case you should get a list of the available methods).

Please do post the results here and hopefully that will help the diagnosis...

---

Thanks for the info!

Having seen the output of the $c.^methods call, it is clear that $c has no method `$c.setPlotArea` (reading the error message says the same - perhaps I should have given that due weight!)

I do not know the Inline::Perl5 module well, but I have seen similar issues with Inline::Python.

My experience in Python is that the target language objects only expose their "direct" methods and do not automatically pull in all the composed methods that they can perform.

My workaround has been on the lines of an "eval" style approach, something like:

```
$p5.run( qq[$c.setPlotArea(30, 20, 200, 200);] );
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks much p6steve - I've edited the original/re-phrased question with requested information and a pointer to full output of Dump $c (the XYChart object).

Comment: thanks @wingfold - very helpful - just to mention that ```say dd $c``` will always return Nil - you need ```dd $c``` ;-)  ... not to worry, the Dump outlook is exactly what I was hoping to see

Comment: thank you again @p6steve - I tried the eval style (i.e., $p5.run( qq[$c.setPlotArea(30, 20, 200, 200);] );) but getting same error message: "No such method 'setPlotArea' for invocant of type 'XYChart'
  in block <unit> at ./test.raku line 32".   I'm out remainder of today but will get back into this tomorrow (Tuesday) (and, of course, post any new results).  Thanks again!